# Get Bitcoin Price and Advice

Tags: python, bitcoin

I wrote this in the last hour because I was bored.  I was hoping I could get some feedback on this.  It is a function that returns the price of a bitcoin and whether you should buy or sell it. I am thinking of setting it up as a function within a chat bot to spice up the chat a little.

```
import urllib2
import random
import json



def bitcoin(currency, amt = 1):
    url = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    the_page = response.read()
    data = json.loads(the_page)
    if currency in ["USD","US","dollar","$"]:
        conversion = data['bpi']['USD']['rate_float']
        symbol = "USD"
    elif currency in ["EUR","EU","euro","€"]:
        conversion = data['bpi']['EUR']['rate_float']
        symbol = "EUR"
    elif currency in ["GBP","GB","UK","pound","£"]:
        conversion = data['bpi']['GBP']['rate_float']
        symbol = "GBP"
    else:
        stop("Currency not recognized.")
    advice = random.choice(["It's so LOW!!!!!!! \r\nBuy!!! Buy!!! Buy!!!!!","It's so HIGH!!!!!! \r\nSell!!! Sell!!! Sell!!!!!"])
    return "{0} Bitcoin = {1} {2} \r\n{3}".format(amt,conversion * amt, symbol, advice)
```

Comment: the `amt` variable designates the amount of bitcoins to convert. This fact is not clear and I had to look into the string formatting in the last line to understand that. I suggest you either give it a more significant name or add a documentation. Also, what does `stop` do?

Comment: Good points. Stop was R.  Should be return. Would a comment '''amt=amount of bitcoin''' or a name "amount_bitcoin" be better?

Comment: I always tend to favor self-explanatory variable names, but it is more a matter of preference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## This is Schrödinger code

It can be both correct and incorrect at the same time.

`random.choice` is not how we offer financial advice.

What I would suggest is to monitor previous data, the longer the better, and monitor the fluctuation in price.

See this graph (Note, a 5 year graph):

[image]

at two points on the chart you can see separate events that can be somewhat predicted by the speed at which it falls/rises in comparison to previous events.

Although this could potentially expand to be a large solution, it's about as close to accurate as you can get. (Not really, but I'm not a market analyst)

[These guys are, though](https://money.stackexchange.com/).

Note that the graph is 5 years; data doesn't fluctuate that much in small amounts.

Although Bitcoin *can*, given it's financially unstable and volatile nature.

Beyond that, your python code is nice :-)

I would suggest writing it to PEP8 however, as that is the official style guide of Python, and then you can use an online checker like [pep8online](http://pep8online.com).

Comment: TIL, what "Schrödinger code" is, what "PEP8" is, and how to be a "market analyst". Thank You!

Comment: `random.choice is not how we offer financial advice.` citation needed

Answer (score 2):

You should split your code into smaller functions, and give them significant names.

For instance

```
def bitcoin(currency, bitcoin_amount = 1):
    currency = normalize_symbol(currency) # returns EUR, USD, GBP or raises Error
    bitcoin_value = bitcoin_value_in(currency) # may raise an Error if currency is unsupported
    currency_amount = bitcoin_amount * bitcoin_value
    advice = random.choice(["It's so LOW!!!!!!! \r\nBuy!!! Buy!!! Buy!!!!!","It's so HIGH!!!!!! \r\nSell!!! Sell!!! Sell!!!!!"])
    return "{0} Bitcoin = {1} {2} \r\n{3}".format(bitcoin_amount, currency_amount, currency, advice)
```

`normalize_symbol` can be implemented with a dict of list: `{'EUR': ['EUR', '€'] ...}`

`bitcoin_value_in` is just a refactorization (move the `url`...`data` code into it)

`advice` has already been studied by @Quill.

Comment: okay, so implementing the dict of list.. you have to return the key if the currency is in the list...  I am thinking you have to use a list comprehension to do that...  `currency = [ki for ki in currencies.keys()if currency in currencies[ki]]`  ... but that returns a list and it searches the whole list for matches and if it finds a match immediately, then it doesn't stop.  How would you recommend implementing this?

Comment: As you mentioned, list comprehension will create a list. You should do a `for symbol, abbreviations in currencies.items():`. If `currency` is in the `abbreviations`, then you return the `symbol`. If the loop terminates, you should raise an exception.